# Is there an advantage of using Table.read_table over pd.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

So far Table.read_table has been giving me headaches as it does not work well with seaborn and matplotlib. However, it is what is being taught in one of my classes.

I am reading this one book, which had pd.read_csv and that has worked wonders. I can do seaborn, matplotlib and other libraries.

In summary, I don't know what the purpose of 'Table.read_table' is since it seems to be limiting with other libraries.

I believe there is something similar with arrays. There is for example 'array([8, 3, 3])' and '([8, 3, 3])' which are not the same thing, however to get some data analysis with other functions, the proper selection needs to be done. It would seem that there is a lot of variations (I've mentioned two) and I would appreciate tips on how to get them properly sorted out or it could be that it just comes with experience.

Example:

Code1 (does not work):

```
data = Table.read_table('IndiaStatus.csv').drop('Discharged', 'Discharge Ratio (%)','Total Cases','Active','Deaths')

sns.jointplot(data=data, x="Death Ratio (%)", y="Active Ratio (%)")
```

[image]

code2 (does work):

```
df = pd.read_csv('IndiaStatus.csv' )

sns.jointplot(data=df, x="Death Ratio (%)", y="Active Ratio (%)")
```

[image]

Comment: Use `sns.jointplot(data=data.to_df(), x="Death Ratio (%)", y="Active Ratio (%)")` in case of Table @Daniel

Comment: This works well. It would help me if you explained the advantage of one (table) over the other (dataframe?).

Comment: I saw the source code. Essentially they use pandas underneath. Does make no sense to me as it doesn't have any added functionality. I think its just for teaching purposes. http://data8.org/datascience/_modules/datascience/tables.html#Table.read_table

Comment: Yeah, seems so. What a waste of time. They should teach the useful stuff.

Comment: ;) You learn a custom unmaintained library throughout the course only to find that it has all been done on many different popular libraries.

Answer (score 0):

read_table is read_csv with sep=',' replaced by sep='\t', they are two thin wrappers around the same function so the performance will be identical. read_excel uses the xlrd package to read xls and xlsx files into a DataFrame, it doesn't handle csv files.

For the same 320 MB CSV file (16 MB .xlsx) (i7-7700k, SSD, running Anaconda Python 3.5.3, Pandas 0.19.2)

Using the standard convention import pandas as pd

2 seconds to read .csv df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv') (same for pd.read_table)

15.3 seconds to read .xlsx df = pd.read_excel('foo.xlsx')

10.5 seconds to write .csv df.to_csv('bar.csv', index=False) (same for .txt)

34.5 seconds to write .xlsx df.to_excel('bar.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).